# SelectedItem always null, while using ViewModel in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I currently try to replicate the idea of the article ["Simplifying the WPF TreeView by Using the ViewModel Pattern"](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode) and build up a TreeView, which has the ItemSource of my generation (like as mentioned in the article), with the exact same template and styles. My data is correctly shown in the TreeView, but the problem is, that if I trigger the event "SelectedItemChanged" I always get the selected item with the value null as a result.

The code of my event is as follows:

```
private void container_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
  TreeViewItem item = container.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
  if(item == null)
    return;

  // some more code ...
}
```

Before I was adding all the items with a foreach loop, like:

```
container.Items.Add(item);
```

There I had already the same problem, so I really don't know, why I can't access the selected item of my tree view. 
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This event will be fired on deselection (e.g. when using data templates and view is unloaded), so `null` might be ok, but check please what you really have `TreeViewItem` type in there, it might be something different (e.g. `{DisconnectedItem}`).

Comment: you can add `container.SelectedItem.GetType()` to check the type of your SelectedItem , may be your cast is returning null .

Comment: Why are you using "container".  With events you should always use the sender.  I would put a break point on first line of code and hover over sender to see what the object type is probably is a TreeViewNode and not an item so you are getting an exception due to the attempting to cast a Node to an item.

Comment: The TreeView.SelectedItemChanged event provides e.NewValue which is of type TreeViewItem. You should be able to work with that.